# How to calculate F-measure based on TPR, FPR and Accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Can anyone help me on this!

I have given TPR (True Positive Rate) and (false positive rate) and the accuracy as well. Based on the given numbers, is there anyway to calculate the f-measure, precision and recall.

Let say that the tpr=.93 FPR=0.17 and the accuracy=0.93. What would be the value of f-measure

Thanks,

Comment: True Positive Rate **is** recall. Unfortunately, neither precision nor f-measure can be calculated from above.

Answer (score 0):

F needs to compute precision and recall (true positive rate).

In the confusion matrix, you have four variables (TP, FP, FN, TN), and since you only need the rates, so you have TP + FP + FN + TN = 1, which essentially makes there only 3 unknown variables. And now you have TPR, FPR, Accuracy, you can have 3 independent equation:

```
TP/(TP+FN) = 0.93
FP/(FP+TN) = 0.17
TP+TN = 0.93
```

then you can figure out how to compute precision, and then F

Comment: this is not true that `TP + FP + FN + TN = 1`, rather `TP + FP + FN + TN = n`,  where `n` is size of the training/test set

Comment: @lejlot if you use *rates* instead of counts... and obviously, the posted used rates, because absolute counts don't have any benefits anyway.

Comment: Of course you can do it, but it is not the definition of TP or any of the others, right? I can see at least few benefits, with the most common - "true positive rate" have completely different meaning in statistics. I completely agree, that it does not change anything in the above computations etc. I was just refering to the established meaning of the acronyms. Am I wrong? Are rates a more common meaning of those?

Comment: Thanks lejlot:d I totally agree that TP + FP + FN + TN = n. I tried to compute the TP and FP but it doesn't work with me.